# "does not contain a definition...and no extension method.." error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, compiler-errors

I have the following error message:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,SpoofClass>' does not
contain a definition for 'biff' and no extension method 'biff'
accepting a first argument of type
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,SpoofClass>' could be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I checked SO for this and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706594/system-web-httppostedfilebase-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-hasfile-and-n) question which seemed to have a similar (if not identical) problem as I am having.  However, I tried the solution provided in the accepted answer and it still isn't coming up with anything.  It's acting like I am missing a using statement, but I am almost positive I have all the using's I need.

Here is some of the code that is producing the errors:

```
using locationOfSpoofClass;
...

Dictionary<int, SpoofClass> cart = new Dictionary<int, SpoofClass>();
foreach (var item in dbContext.DBView)
{
    cart.biff = item.biff;
    ...
}
```

SpoofClass file:

```
namespace locationOfSpoofClass
{
    public class SpoofClass
    {
        public int biff { get; set; }
        ...
    }
}
```

Sorry if my renaming of variables and whatnot is confusing.  If it is unreadable, or too hard to follow, or if other information is pertinent to the solution, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this part: `cart.biff`. `cart` is of type `Dictionary<int, SpoofClass>`, not of type `SpoofClass`.

I can only guess what you are trying to do, but the following code compiles:

```
Dictionary<int, SpoofClass> cart = new Dictionary<int, SpoofClass>();
int i=0;
foreach (var item in dbContext.DBView)
{
    cart.Add(i, new SpoofClass { biff = item.biff });
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to access the Value of the Dictionary for a given key.  Something along these lines.

```
foreach(var item in dbContext.DBView)
{
    foreach(var key in cart.Keys)
    {
        cart[key].biff = item.biff;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code would not compile as cart[key] has a type of SpoofClass whereas item.biff is an int.

Comment: @Dylan: Now your code compiles but it makes no sense :) After the loops all entries in the dictionary will have the `biff` value of the last item in the `DBView`.

Comment: @Daniel, whilst you are correct it sort of looks like that is what the OP wants to do ;-)