# “does not contain a definition…and no extension method..” error

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

I am having an issue whereby I cannot use an objects method because of this error:

> Does not contain a definition...and no extension method...

It is very related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178151/does-not-contain-a-definition-and-no-extension-method-error). I am doing what is given as the answer in that question, but I am still getting this error.

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModel
{
    public class NetworkHealthViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private IDataService _dataService;
        public ObservableCollection<NetworkBandwidthModel> NbicNetworkBandwidth
        public ObservableCollection<NetworkPortalStatusModel> NbicNetworkPortalStatus

        public NetworkHealthViewModel()
        {
            _dataService = new DataServiceNetworkHealth();
            NbicNetworkBandwidth       = new ObservableCollection<NetworkBandwidthModel>();
            NbicNetworkPortalStatus    = new ObservableCollection<NetworkPortalStatusModel>();
            _dataService.LoadChartItems(NetworkBandwidthLoaded, NetworkBandwidthLoadedFailed);
            _dataService.LoadPortalStatus(NetworkPortalStatusLoaded, NetworkPortalStatusLoadedFailed);
         }
```

The error lies at LoadPortalStatus(). LoadChartItems() is fine. NetworkBandwidthLoaded and NetworkPortalStatusLoaded are delegates.

NetworkPortalStatusLoaded is laid out pretty much the same as NetworkBandwidthLoaded:

```
private void NetworkPortalStatusLoaded(IEnumerable<ChartModel> portalStatItems) 
{
    NbicNetworkPortalStatus.Clear();

    var networkPortalItems = from item in portalStatItems
                             where ((NetworkPortalStatusModel)item).Unit == "Portal"
                             select item;

    foreach (var item in networkPortalItems)
    {
        NbicNetworkPortalStatus.Add((NetworkPortalStatusModel)item);
    }

    Message = "Network Portal details loaded";
}
```

My DataServiceNetworkHealth class is defined as:

```
namespace MyProject.DataServices
{
    public class DataServiceNetworkHealth : IDataService
    {
        private Action<IEnumerable<ChartModel>> _delagateSuccess;
        private Action<Exception> _delagateFail;
        private String _portalHtmlResponse;

        public void LoadChartItems(Action<IEnumerable<ChartModel>> success, Action<Exception> fail)
        {
          ....
        }

        public void LoadPortalStatus(Action<IEnumerable<ChartModel>> success, Action<Exception> fail)
        {
          ....
        }
    }
}
```

Method LoadChartItems() is defined in the interface IDataService, but LoadPortalStatus is not. Perhaps that's where the problem lies. There are other DataServiceX classes that do not use LoadPortalStatus.

I know this is a long post, but I thought better to give all info up front. :-)  Thanks for any help!

Comment: What **exactly** method can't be located by the compiler?!

Comment: I don't see a `LoadPortalStatus` method in your code...

Comment: If the `DataServiceNetworkHealth` class does not declare the `LoadPortalStatus` method, then you cannot call that method on an instance of that class. Simple. What am I missing? :)

Comment: Where is your `LoadPortalStatus` method declared. I don't see any and that's why it's erroring.

Comment: Yes. That was a total copy-and-paste error. I just updated the code post. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reference to `_dataService` is of the type `IDataService`, which means that you can only access members defined by this interface (or extension methods for said interfae). You mention that `LoadPortalStatus` isn't part of that interface and thus you cannot access it through the `_dataService` reference.

Updated based on comment: Let's look at another example. If you define a `List<int>` reference like this:

```
List<int> i = new List<int>();
```

you can access all the members of `List<T>()` and all the members of `Object`. However, if you change the reference to

```
IEnumerable<int> i = new List<int>();
```

the only accessible members through `i` are `GetEnumerator` which is defined on `IEnumerable<T>` and the members inherited from `Object`.

If you include the `System.Linq` namespace, you also get access to the numerous extension methods defined for `IEnumerable<T>`.

The static type of `i` determines which members are available through that reference.

Comment: This may seem like a silly question, but are you saying that I cannot define additional methods in class MyClass (i.e. MyClass : IMyInterface) that were not defined in IMyInterface? Do I have to create an additional derived class for that?

Comment: I'm saying that if you reference the instance through a specific interface then that is the contract that defines what part of the members of the instance you have access to. I.e. the interface and any extension methods defined for that interface is the members you can access (along with the members for Object of course).

Comment: I've updated my answer with another example. Hopefully that explains it a little better.

Comment: That totally makes sense. The reason I was calling

    private IDataService _dataService;

was because using MVVM Light, one creates a class of a data service (of type IDataService) for production use and a class (again of type IDataService) for design time use. I hadn't implemented those methods in the design time class. Also since none of my other DataService classes were using those methods, I didnt think to include those methods in the IDataService. 

In the end, I simply made 

    private IDataService _dataService;

into

    private DataServiceNetworkHealth _dataService;
 
Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

If `LoadPortalStatus` is not available in the interface (or an extension method on that interface), then it can't be called from an instance of the interface.

Since you define:

```
private IDataService _dataService;
```

This means that you can only access things in `_dataService` declared in the `IDataService` (or as an extension method) interface, regardless of what the implementation of that interface is.

So your choices are:

1) make _dataService variable a type that has `LoadPortalStatus` defined.
2) add `LoadPortalStatus` to the `IDataService` interface.
3) Create an extension method for `IDataService` called `LoadPortalStatus`

Any of those would work, though 1 or 2 would probably be preferable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This might be overly obvious, but could you be getting this error because you don't actually have a `LoadPortalStatus` method in your code?

You have multiple `LoadChartItems` methods with identical signatures -- is it possible that one of these is supposed to be the `LoadPortalStatus()` method?

```
public void LoadChartItems(Action<IEnumerable<ChartModel>> success, Action<Exception> fail)
{
    ....
}

//Same signature as above - is this supposed to implement LoadPortalStatus??
public void LoadChartItems(Action<IEnumerable<ChartModel>> success, Action<Exception> fail)
{
    ....
}
```