# How to call the reference from one class to another class using PRISM

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I just stucked up to call the reference from one class to another class but both classes are in different project in same solution.

Here is what am trying to do.

Project A (Webster.Client.Modules.Metadata)
Class Name : Helper.cs

Projec B (Webster.Client.Infrastructure)

Class Name: ImageResizerService.cs

Interface: IImageResizerService.cs
I trying to use helper class  in my ImageResizerService class.

When i try to add the project reference,it throws "A Reference to Webster.Client.Modules.Metadata could not be added. Adding this project as refernce would cause a circular dependency"

Comment: can you provide us a message why the reference breaks your `whole project`

Comment: I couldn't able to see the reference,for eg,if try "using Webster.Client.Modules.Metadata;" in my ImageResizer class,it doesn't understand at all

Comment: When i try to add the project reference,it throws "A Reference to Webster.Client.Modules.Metadata could not be added. Adding this project as refernce would cause a circular dependency"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [MSDN solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/43645215-9d09-4435-961e-2255a4c19d85/). Prism is not your problem.

Or [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093908/cannot-add-reference-to-project-because-of-a-circular-dependency-error). May be your question is duplicate.

Comment: thanks stukselbax,I don't know i can't reference vice versa.Thanks again